Upper bound of $\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n-2} (1+x)^{n} e^{-cx^2}{_2F_1}(-\frac{n}{2},n-1;n-0.5;x)dx$
The integral is
$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n-2} (1+x)^{n} e^{-cx^2}{_2F_1}(-\frac{n}{2},n-1;n-0.5;x)dx$,
where $n$ is a positive integer, $c$ is a positive real number and $c$ is around the same magnitude with n ($c$~$n$).
Is there a closed-form result of this integral, or alternatively an upper bound?
I have tried several methods to obtain an upper bound, mainly by separating $e^{-cx^2}$ and the hypergeometric part (since there is no exisiting result of a integral with both, to best of my knowledge). But the monotonicity of the separated parts can not match.
Another way is to expand the hypergeometric function and the term $(1+x)^{b}$. The result is a sum of series of incomplete gamma function, but the part $-\frac{n}{2}$ in the hypergeometric funtion makes the sum alternating, which makes it difficult to obtain any bound.
Finally, I tried
${_2F_1}(-\frac{n}{2},n-1;n-0.5;x)=(1-x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}{_2F_1}(\frac{3n}{2}+0.5,0.5;n-0.5;x)$
which solves the alternating problem, but the introduction of the term $(1-x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}{_2F_1}$ makes the result a sum of series with ${_1F_1}$, which is much more difficult to deal with comparing to incomplete gamma function.

I guess I found the asymptotics of your integral at $n\gg1$. I will check tomorrow and, if everything is correct, post the solution.

We will find the asymptotic of the integral at $n\to\infty$.
Using the  integral representation
$\,_2F_1(a,b;c;x)=\frac1{B(b,\,c-b)}\int_0^1z^{b-1}(1-z)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a}dz,\, c>b>0$
$$_2F_1\Big(-\frac n2,n-1;n-\frac12;x\Big)=\frac1{B\big(n-1;\frac12\big)}\int_0^1 z^{n-2}(1-z)^{-\frac12}(1-zx)^\frac n2dz\tag{1}$$
The condition $c>b>0$ is met ($n-\frac12>n-1>0$).
Using (1)
$$I(n,c)=\frac1{B\big(n-1;\frac12\big)}\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1dz\,\,e^{-cx^2}(1-z)^{-\frac12}z^{n-2}(1-zx)^\frac n2 x^{2n-2}(1+x)^n$$
$$=\frac1{B\big(n-1;\frac12\big)}\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1dz\,\,e^{-cx^2}(1-z)^{-\frac12}z^{-2}x^{-2}e^{n(2\ln x+\ln(1+x)+\ln z+\frac12\ln(1-zx)}$$
We see that the function $f(x,z)=2\ln x+\ln(1+x)+\ln z+\frac12\ln(1-zx)$ does not have an extremum inside $(x,z)\in(0;1)\times(0;1)$. Indeed,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,z)=\frac2x+\frac1{1+x}-\frac z{2(1-zx)}\tag{a}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z)=\frac1z-\frac x{2(1-zx)}\text{(A small typo has been corrected)}\tag{b}$$
Multiplying (a) and (b) respectively by $x$ and $z$ and taking the difference,
$$\frac x{1+x}+1\neq0$$
It means that the function $f(x,z)$ can only have conditional extremum on the border of the area. It is straightforward to see (without a proof from  my side) that this conditional maximum is reached at $x\to1$. Making the substitution $x=1-t$
$$I(n,c)=\frac{2^n}{B\big(n-1;\frac12\big)}\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{e^{-c(1-t)^2}}{(1-t)^2}\frac{e^{n\big(2\ln(1-t)+\ln(1-\frac t2)\big)}}{\sqrt{1-z}}(1-z+tz)^\frac n2z^nz^{-2} dtdz$$
Using also
$$B\big(n-1;\frac12\big)=\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=2\int_0^1e^{(n-2)\ln(1-t^2)}dt\sim2\int_0^\infty e^{(n-2)t^2}dt\sim\sqrt{\frac\pi n}$$
and considering $t\ll1$, we are getting the main asymptotic term:
$$I(n,c)\sim\sqrt{\frac n\pi }2^ne^{-c}\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{-\frac52nt}(1-z+zt)^\frac n2\frac1{\sqrt{1-z}}\frac{z^{n}}{z^2}dtdz$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac n\pi}2^ne^{-c}\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{-\frac52nt}(1+\frac{zt}{1-z})^\frac n2\frac{(1-z)^\frac n2}{\sqrt{1-z}}\frac{z^{n}}{z^2}dtdz$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac n\pi}2^ne^{-c}\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{-\frac52nt}(1+\frac{zt}{1-z})^\frac n2\frac{e^{n\big(\ln z+\frac12\ln(1-z)\big)}}{z^2\sqrt{1-z}}dtdz$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac n\pi}2^ne^{-c}\frac 2{5n}\int_0^{\frac{5n}2}e^{-x}dx\int_0^1\Big(1+\frac{2zx}{5(1-z)n}\Big)^\frac n2\frac{e^{n\big(\ln z+\frac12\ln(1-z)\big)}}{z^2\sqrt{1-z}}dz$$
The function $g(z)=\ln z+\frac12\ln(1-z)$ reaches its maximum at $z_0=\frac23;\,g''(z_0)=-\frac{27}4$. Using Laplace' method
$$I\sim\sqrt{\frac n\pi}\frac {2^{n+1}e^{-c}}{5n}\frac{e^{n\big(\ln z_0+\frac12\ln(1-z_0)\big)}}{z_0^2\sqrt{1-z_0}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x+\frac{z_0x}{5(1-z_0)}}dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{27ns^2}8}ds$$
Integrating and putting $z_0=\frac23$, after straightforward transformations we get the main asymptotic term:
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n,c)\sim \frac{e^{-c}}{n}\frac{2^{2n+\frac12}}{3^\frac{3n}2},\,\,n\gg1\,\,}$$
The analysis shows that $\displaystyle I(n,c)\sim \frac{e^{-c}}{n}\frac{2^{2n+\frac12}}{3^\frac{3n}2}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1n\Big)\right)$.
We have a reasonable numeric agreement even at low $n$: for example, at $c=0$ and $n=20$
$\displaystyle I(20,0)=0.000396...;\,\,\text{approximation}=0.000377...$; the difference $\approx 5$% $= \frac1{20}$
(https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%28x%5E%7B38%7D%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B20%7D+2F1%5B-10%2C+19%2C+19.5%2C+x%5D%29dx and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%5E%2840.5%29%2F3%5E%2830%29%2F20)
I cannot check the answer for bigger $n$: WA does not evaluate the integral correctly (even negative values appear - for example, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%28x%5E%7B98%7D%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B50%7D+2F1%5B-25%2C+49%2C+49.5%2C+x%5D%29dx)

With Mathematica: $I(100,0)=6.1956810^-14$ approximation=$6.1422210^-14$;

@ Mariusz Iwaniuk, thank you! It works :)

As expected, the accuracy at $n=100$ is approx. $\sim\frac1{100}=1$%

@Svyatoslav Thank you for your answer, the form of the asymptotic is quite simple which is nice. I have two questions. 1. when $c$ is large (say around the magnitude of $n$), the asymptotic becomes loose. In this case, can we just put $\frac{c}{n}$ into $f(x,z)$? The required conditions (conditional extremum) seems still vaild. 2. Actually, I can allow the term $B(n-1, 0.5)$ in my final result. In this case the only approximation happens at the last Laplace's method. Is there any way to come across an strict upper bound?

$$1.\quad(1+x)^n\overset{x=1-t}{=}(2-t)^n=2^n\big(1-\frac t2\big)^n=2^ne^{n\ln(1-\frac t2)}$$
2.  no, we cannot just put $\frac cn$. If $c$ is comparable with $n$, it will be a completely different, more complicated case. 3. For the given approach the only way to get a stricter bound is evaluation of the next $\Big(O\big(\frac1n\big)\Big)$ asymptotic term

@Svyatoslav Thank you for your reply. I can understand your answer for my question 1 and 3. But for question 2, it seems to me that the only change when put $\frac{c}{n}$ is additional terms in the integral w.r.t. $x$. Currently, it is $\int e^{-x}dx$. When put $\frac{c}{n}$, it becomes something like $\int e^{-x-\frac{2}{5}\frac{c}{n}(x)^2} dx$ (not exactly), which can also obtianed a strict upper bound easily if using erfc.

This is your problem, and this is you choice on how to handle it (and be responsible for the correctness of the answer).  In the case of $c\sim n$ the extremum moves from the region $x\approx 1$ , from the bound of the interval, and you have to find a new point of maximum (which depends on two variables - $x$ and $z$), what is a totally new case (let alone that there can be different cases, depending on how big is $c ,(c\sim n;,c\sim\sqrt n...)$). Anyway, I wish you good luck in solving your problem.

@Svyatoslav Thanks for your great help. I will continue with your method to check if there any possible way to obtain a relatively simple maximum. And I think I have to spend more time researching Laplace's method to handle the higher order remainer terms (which is more difficult from my perspective). Thank you again, have a nice day.

Too long for a comment.
$$I_n=\, _2F_1\left(n-1,-\frac{n}{2};n-\frac{1}{2};x\right)\,dx$$ seems to be more than difficult.
Even if we use
$$\, _2F_1\left(n-1,-\frac{n}{2};n-\frac{1}{2};x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\, x^k$$ the calculation of
$$J_k=\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n-2+k}\, (1+x)^{n}\, e^{-cx^2}\,dx$$ is explicit for a given value of $n$ (as you noticed, it involves the complete and incomplete gamma function and powers of $c$) but it is quickly messy not to say more. I prefer not to think about the summation over $k$.
Using Mathematica, what I noticed is that $I_1$ and $I_2$ have rather simple expressions but no result for any odd value of $n$.
For even $n$, there are results which write
$$I_{2n}=\sqrt {\pi c}\, P_n \,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{c}\right)+Q_n\,e^{-c}+R_n$$ where the $P_n$,  $Q_n$ and $R_n$  are polynomials in  $\frac{1}{c}$.
For example, for $I_{6}$
$$P_{6}=\frac{945}{64 c^6}+\frac{155925}{1664c^7}-\frac{876015}{256 c^8}+\frac{13650525}{512c^9}-\frac{9398025}{128c^{10}}$$ and
$$Q_{6}=-\frac{32}{143 c}-\frac{96}{143 c^2}-\frac{252}{143
   c^3}+\frac{288}{143 c^4}+\frac{2448}{13
   c^5}+\frac{2224125}{832 c^6}+\frac{3671595}{176
   c^7}+\frac{3427769205}{36608
   c^8}+\frac{2528357895}{9152 c^9}+\frac{20321280}{143
   c^{10}}$$ and
$$R_{6}=\frac{2160}{11 c^6}-\frac{339120}{143
   c^7}+\frac{120960}{13 c^8}+\frac{1814400}{143
   c^9}-\frac{20321280}{143
   c^{10}}$$

Thank you for the answer. I've tried this integral for almost half a year with dozens of methods. As this integral is a part of my work in the information theory, my goal is to get a tight upper bound with simple closed-form. However, none of my trials meeet both demands. Speaking of the asymtopics of the $_2F_1$, for small $x$ it approximates to $(1-x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ (a lower bound), for large $x$ it approximates to ${_2F_1}(-\frac{n}{2},n-0.5;n-1;1)\sqrt{n}x^{1-n}$ (an upper bound). They are tight in their domain. But I havn't found any upper bound that is tight for all $x\in(0,1)$.
