How to calculate an upper bound for $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-x)^k}{\sqrt{k+a}}$
As the title mentioned, I want to get a closed-form result of
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-x)^k}{\sqrt{k+a}},
\end{equation}
where $x\in[0,1]$ is a real number, and $a$ is a positive integer in the same magnitude of $n$ ($a$~$n$).
I believe the exact result contains some kind of hyper-function (Lerch transcendent function or hypergeometric function). Since I want a simple closed-form result, an upper bound seems to be the only option.

For $0<x<1$ and $a>0$ , heuristically, we can get the following asymptotics
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-x)^k}{\sqrt{k+a}}\sim\sqrt{\frac2a}\left(\frac a{nx}\right)^a\frac{e^{-a}}{\sqrt{\ln\frac{nx}a}}\quad \text{for},,\frac{nx}a\gg1$$
Numeric check with WA confirms the answer (for example, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B1000%7D+%28%5Cbinom%7B1000%7D%7Bk%7D+%28-0.5%29%5Ek%2F%5Csqrt%7Bk%2B1.2%7D%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%7B-1.2%7D%5Csqrt2%2Fsqrt%281.2%29%281.2%2F%28500%29%29%5E%7B1.2%7D%2F%5Csqrt%7B%5Cln%28500%2F1.2%29%7D)

@Svyatoslav Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, in my exact case, $a$ is quite large (almost $2n$). I am sorry for not mentioning this condition. Is it possible to cover this case with some modification?

@Svyatoslav With more observation, the term $(\frac{a}{nx})^a$ seems to be fine with large $a$, the point is to modificate the $\ln\frac{nx}{a}$ to suppress the sum when $x\to 0$. Without the term of $\sqrt{\ln\frac{nx}{a}}$ in the denominator, the asymptotic goes to infinity when $x\to 0$

c'est une autre paire de manches :) For the case $,a,n\gg1$ and $a>\frac{xn}{1-x}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-x)^k}{\sqrt{k+a}}\sim\frac{(1-x)^n}{\sqrt{a-\frac{xn}{1-x}}}$$
WA quick check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%28%5Cbinom%7B100%7D%7Bk%7D+%28-0.3%29%5Ek%2F%5Csqrt%7Bk%2B150%7D%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-0.3%29%5E100%2F%5Csqrt%7B150-30%2F0.7%7D

Also, even for rather small $a,n,$  ($\sim10$) there is a good numeric agreement: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D+%28%5Cbinom%7B10%7D%7Bk%7D+%28-0.3%29%5Ek%2F%5Csqrt%7Bk%2B15%7D%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-0.3%29%5E10%2F%5Csqrt%7B15-3%2F0.7%7D

If you also need the case $a<\frac{xn}{1-x}$ - please, let me know.

@Svyatoslav Thank you for your reply. Since that $x\in[0,1]$, then $\frac{xn}{1-x}\in [0,\infty)$. In my problem, I have to integral the sum w.r.t. $x$ from 0 to 1, so I think I also need the case for $a<\frac{xn}{1-x}$. In addition, can you provide the derivation for this asymptoptic if possible?

Moreover, since the outside integtal also contains $e^{-cx^2}$ (where $c$ is a positive real number), it would be convenient to have a consist asyptotic (if possible) for $\forall x\in[0,1]$, so that the result of the integral can be written in Gamma function.

Yes, I will provide the solution. Could you provide the wider information about the problem you are solving? You mentioned integration with respect to $x$; there could be more straightforward (and accurate) ways than finding asymptotics of the sum

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4920710/upper-bound-of-int-01x2n-2-1xn-e-cx2-2f-1-fracn2-n-1

This is the exact problem I am solving, which is quite difficult to solve directly. I try to solve the hypergeometric function first and come across this problem in this list, which seems to be easier.
