How to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k$
As the title mentioned, I want to calculate
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k,
\end{equation}
where $n$ and $a$ are both positive integer, and $x\in[0,1]$.
There is an obvious upper bound as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k=(1-x)^{-a-1},
\end{equation}
which is too loose for my application. Therefore, is it possible to obtain the exact result of this sum? Or at least a strict upper bound tighter than the above one. BTW, I came to this sum from hypergeometric function (or imcomplete beta function with transform in form), so I do not want to go back.

I just came from hypergeometric function, so I want a simple closed-form bound. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

The exact result is the hypergeometric function, you cannot have anything simpler.

I just hope for a simple upper bound tighter than $(1-x)^{-a-1}$. I don't know there is any.

(Long comment) I am skeptical about the existence of a simple closed form for the sum. However, we have some alternative representation of the series that might be possibly useful in the case

$a$ if fixed and $n$ is increasing, or
$x$ is close to $1$.

Below is such a representation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1+a}{n-k} x^{n-k}(1 - x)^{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}} \left[ 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{n+1+a}{k} x^{n+1+a-k}(1 - x)^k \right]
\end{align*}
In the last expression, tossing the entire inner sum away recovers the crude bound $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}}$, whereas keeping (part of) it gives a better upper bound.

Also, for $x \in [0, 1]$ this representation admits the following reformulation in terms of probability: Let $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n+1+a, x)$ be a binomial random variable with parameterx $n+1+a$ and $x$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a+k}{a} x^k
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1+a}{n-k} x^{n-k}(1 - x)^{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}} \left[ 1 - \mathbf{P}(X > n) \right].
\end{align*}
Hence, if $x$ is sufficiently close to $1$ so that $\mathbf{E}[X] > n$, we can invoke several tail estimates from the probability theory to give an upper bound.

Example. If $\mathbf{E}[X] > n$, or equivalently $x > \frac{n}{n+a+1}$, then by Hoeffding's inequality,
\begin{align*}
1 - \mathbf{P}(X > n)
&= \mathbf{P}(X - \mathbf{E}[X] \leq -(\mathbf{E}[X] - n) ) \\
&\leq \exp\left( -\frac{2(\mathbf{E}[X] - n)^2}{n+a+1} \right) \\
&= \exp\left( -2(n+a+1)\left(x- \frac{n}{n+a+1}\right)^2 \right).
\end{align*}
This is particularly useful when $a \gg n$.


Thank you for your answer. The bound is definitely tighter, but the required condition of $x>\frac{n}{n+a+1}$ is annoying to my application. The result of this question need to be integrated w.r.t. $x$ from 0 to 1 (this sum is only part of the integral function, you can refer the full question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4920710/upper-bound-of-int-01x2n-2-1xn-e-cx2-2f-1-fracn2-n-1), so I want to get a consistant form for any $x\in[0,1]$ (I know it's difficult), otherwise it is more difficult to integral.

Anyway, I think the answer has solved this exact question very well, thank you again.

Let $$f(x;a,n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{a+k}{a} x^k. \tag{1}$$
Then $$f(x;a,\infty) = (1-x)^{-(a+1)}, \quad |x| < 1 \tag{2}$$ as this is a negative binomial series.
The evaluation of this sum for finite $n$ can be expressed in terms of the incomplete beta function:
$$f(x;a,n) = \frac{1 - (n+1) {\operatorname{B}}_x(n+1, a+1) \binom{a+n+1}{a}}{(1-x)^{a+1}},  \quad |x| < 1, \tag{3}$$
where $${\operatorname{B}}_z(a,b) = \int_{t=0}^z t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \, dt \tag{4}$$
is the incomplete beta function.  However, this is not a particularly helpful result, since the evaluation of $(4)$ and subsequently $(3)$ for positive integer values $a, n$ only leads back to $(1)$.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I just came from hypergeometric function, so definitely do not want to go back.

Here is my solution.
Let $f(a) = \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k$
$xf(a) = \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^{k+1}$
$(1-x)f(a)= \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k - \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^{k+1}$
$= 1 + \sum_{k =1}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k - \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^{k+1}$ (Note k starts from 1 in the first summation.)
$= 1 + \sum_{k =1}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k - \sum_{k =1}^{n+1}{a+k-1 \choose a}x^{k}$ (Note some manipulations the second summation .)
$= 1 + \sum_{k =1}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k - \sum_{k =1}^{n}{a+k-1 \choose a}x^{k}-{{a+n}\choose a} x^{n+1}$
$= 1 + \sum_{k =1}^{n}\left({a+k \choose a}-{a+k-1 \choose a}\right)x^k -{{a+n}\choose a} x^{n+1}$
$=1 + \sum_{k =1}^{n}{a+k-1 \choose a-1}x^k -{{a+n}\choose a} x^{n+1}$ (because $\left({a+k \choose a}-{a+k-1 \choose a}\right) = {a+k-1 \choose a-1}$)
$=\sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k-1 \choose a-1}x^k -{{a+n}\choose a} x^{n+1}$
$= f(a-1) - {{a+n}\choose a} x^{n+1}$
Then we have
$f(a) = \frac{1}{1-x} f(a-1) - {{a+n}\choose a} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$
$= \frac{1}{1-x} f(a-1) - {{a+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$
Expand this,
$f(a) = \frac{1}{1-x} \left(\frac{1}{1-x} f(a-2) - {{a-1+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right) - {{a+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$
$=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}f(a-2)- {{a-1+n}\choose n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}- {{a+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} $
$=\ ...$
$=\frac{1}{(1-x)^a}f(0)- {{1+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^a} - {{2+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{a-1}} - ... - {{a+n}\choose n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$
$= \frac{1}{(1-x)^a}f(0) - x^{n+1}\sum_{k = 1}^{a}{{a+n+1-k} \choose n} \frac{1}{(1-x)^k}$
Now we have $f(0) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$,
$\sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k=f(a) = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}} - x^{n+1}\sum_{k = 1}^{a}{{a+n+1-k} \choose n} \frac{1}{(1-x)^k}$
I've done simple verifications as follows.
Let $a = 2, n = 2$,
$f(2) = 1 + 3x + 6x^2$ (by plugging in the original form.)
$f(2) = \frac{1-x^{3}}{{(1-x)}^3}- x^{3}\sum_{k = 1}^{2}{{5-k} \choose 2} \frac{1}{(1-x)^k}$ (by plugging in the derived result.)
$= \frac{1+x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}- x^3\left(\frac{6}{1-x} + \frac{3}{(1-x)^2} \right)$
$=\frac{6x^4 - 9x^3+x^2+x+1}{(1-x)^2}$
$=1 + 3x + 6x^2$
An obvious bound:
For $0<x<1, \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k <\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}}$.
Another bound:
For $0<x<1, \sum_{k =0}^{n}{a+k \choose a}x^k <\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}}-x^{n+1}\sum_{k = 1}^{a}\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}} - x^n \left((1-x)^{-a}-1\right)$ (by sum of geometric sequence.)
Finally given that ${a+n+1-k} \choose n$ appears in the result, we can derive more interesting bounds based on results of the bounds of general ${n \choose k}$. Some discussions are found here

Thank you for your answer. The proof is clean and elegent, and the result is simple as demanded. Unfortuantely, the two bounds are almost the same as $(1+x)^{-a-1}$ when comparing the tightness. Anyway, thank you for your answer, your answer provides a new perspective of the question, I am working on it to see if tighter bounds can be obtained.

If we denote the sum in the question as $f(a,n,x)$, then according to your answer with some easy manipulation, we have $f(a,n,x)=\frac{1-x^{n+1}f(n,a,1-x))}{(1-x)^{a+1}}$, which seems very interesting.

Glad this helps!
